# Developing Wordpress plugin - php, javascript - image maps

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm looking for someone to help me develop wordpress plugin like this:
https://codecanyon.net/item/image-map-pro-for-wordpress-interactive-image-map-builder/2826664

Comment: This really is not the place to look for help for full builds.

Answer (score 0):

You should really hire someone who has better understanding and proper knowledge of wordpress core and plugin development in a professional way.

Actually stack overflow might not be the best one for you.
Try looking http://jobs.wordpress.net/